# Format local file system HDFS and launch Hadoop

Tags: hadoop, hdfs

I am working on OpenClassroom and trying to understand Hadoop, but I have some problems installing it (I am kinda new on Linux):

I have installed and configured Hadoop (I have changed the files `etc/hadoop/core-site.xml`, `etc/hadoop/hdfs-site.xml`, `etc/hadoop/mapred-site.xml` and `etc/hadoop/yarn-site.xml` as asked in the website)

But after, they tell me to do that in order to launch Hadoop:

```
$ hdfs namenode -format
$ start-dfs.sh
$ start-yarn.sh
```

But when I do it, it gives me:

> hdfs : command can't be found

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

The issue can happen in the below scenarios:-

> 1) hdfs binaries are not installed properly
>
> 2) The location of the hdfs execuatble script is not present in $PATH
>   of the user who is executing the command. To verify the same, try the
>   below steps:-
>
> A) Please clarify if the hdfs binaries is installed by navigating to
>   the location "/usr/hdp//hadoop-hdfs/bin" directory.
>
> B) Please check if /usr/bin directory and HADOOP_HOME is present in
>   the $PATH environment variable? (echo $PATH)
>
> C) Output of the command ls -ltr /usr/bin/hdfs. By default a softlink
>   is created for hdfs script in usr/bin directory.

Comment: This solution for hortonworks platform, you can check in similar directories for other platforms.

Comment: Thank you for your help I will check this when I'll have a moment